# What is the right idea for Project Euler Problem 3?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

For everyone who needs the problem itself:
"The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?"

So I'm sitting here trying to solve it with JavaScript. I don't want to google it because then I get exact solutions which I don't want. I just wanted to ask if anyone could tell me if I do something terribly wrong or if I have the right idea and I only miss something (?) and what I could think about improving, without telling me the direct answer.
Also the code is not finished yet (need to sort the array by the biggest number, also my browser crashes/loads ultimatly long when executing the function so there must be something wrong with the loop too).

Thanks in advance.

```
function solve() {
  var divider = 2;
  var n = 600851475143;
  var item = 0;
  var arr = [];
  for (divider = 2; divider <= n; divider++) {
    if (n % divider === 0) {
      item = n / divider;
      arr.push(item);
    } else {
      divider++;
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: *"I don't want to google it"* Except that is expected here. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: A question has to be self-contained. Any information relevant for the problem has to be part of the question itself. A link to an external resource is not enough.

Comment: A lot of Project Euler's problems rely on more of an understanding of math than programming, so the people here might not be that receptive. I'll point out that you're iterating through every integer, rather than every prime number. You probably should incorporate some aspect of prime factors to make this more efficient too. A general tip: if you're iterating through more than a billion of something, look for some optimizations

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the answer steve. I guess that's whats missing in my function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6184972/steve) pointed out in the comments:

> "A lot of Project Euler's problems rely on more of an understanding of
> math than programming, so the people here might not be that receptive.
> I'll point out that you're iterating through every integer, rather
> than every prime number. You probably should incorporate some aspect
> of prime factors to make this more efficient too. A general tip: if
> you're iterating through more than a billion of something, look for
> some optimizations"

So I actually implement a prime check.

Comment: Actually, you don't need prime numbers here, your algorithm ("trial division"), if implemented properly, should give the result in a fraction of second. Hint: start with 3, not 2 and only check odd numbers.